# Sharepoint granular security question

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm setting up a knowledgebase using a nice Sharepoint template I've found. So far, it looks like it will fit the bill nicely. However, I have some questions re: the general security of SP itself. In the image below, there are the link bars on the left. In its simplest form, I would like "Visitors" to only SEE the stuff under **Knowledge Base**, but the **Common Actions** to not be visible. Right now, just adding them to the "Visitors" group, they are able to see the links, but clicking them gives an access denied. I'd like to just hide them altogether for that security group. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by setting an **Audience** on the Common Actions group of links.

To do this, go to Site Actions >> Site Settings and click on Navigation.  Under Navigation Editing and Sorting, select the Common Actions folder, and click Edit.

In the Audience field, use the address book to select the Distribution/Security Group or SharePoint Group for which you want to limit visibility to.

Comment: Got it, now it just doesn't want to add groups. I'll need to figure that out separately. Thanks. Once I get this tested and working, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Dan That can happen on some templates. Try appending "/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx" to the end of the base URL of the site.

Comment: @Dan Instead of using groups, you could create a new audience for your help desk technicians through the shared services admin page.